# XY coordinate data cleansing - search split and append not co mingling

Tags: arcpy, cursor

My first question posted is for a project that stemmed from my current work where the data entered had some minor coordinate issues but to the extent of the data not being able to import more than 50% of the records. the company has archived these records because of the time to manually fix them so I took this python course and thought hey I am going to learn how to fix that at a press of a button... and I have come this far.

I have some minor errors and I believe that the search for multi, then split and append new rows are disjointed. Part of the issue is that I had it "together" but my lecture reformatted to be more elegant and now I can't re associate the sections plus mine wasn't controlled and indexing at all. I know my bad.

working is the aim rather than using other functions and such but the report is written the

```
import arcpy.da

workspace = r"F:\GEOM7004\Project\data.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

orig_table = 'SampleData'
in_table = 'SampleDataCleaned'
fields = ('GPS_X', 'GPS_Y', 'CODE_X', 'CODE_Y','UID')

print ("Original Data called: " + orig_table)

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(orig_table, workspace, in_table)
print("Creating new output table called: " + in_table)
print ("Output table with correct or coded coordinates: " + in_table)

#orig_table=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#AddField_management (in_table, field_name, field_type, {field_precision}, {field_scale}, {field_length},
#{field_alias}, {field_is_nullable}, {field_is_required}, {field_domain})

arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, "CODE_X", "TEXT", '', '', 20,'','NULLABLE')
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, 'CODE_Y', "TEXT", '', '', 20,'', 'NULLABLE')

arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, 'OUT_X', "DOUBLE" , "", "", 10, "", "NULLABLE")
# create field for Y coordinate code
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, 'OUT_Y', "DOUBLE" , "", "", 10, "", "NULLABLE")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0] #to check
        if row[0]== None:
            row[2] = "missing coord"
        elif len(row[0])== 6:
            row[2] ="ok" #[3] to access the code_x field in fields
        elif len(row[0]) >=7:
            row[2] = "multi" # multi not running
        elif len(row[0])<6:
            row[2] = "dud"
        print row[1]
        if row[1]== None:
            row[3] = "missing coord"
        elif len(row[1])== 7:
            row[3] ="ok" #[3] to access the code_x field in fields
        elif len(row[1]) >=8:
            row[3] = "multi" # multi not running consider str/int issue on J
        elif len(row[1])<7:
            row[3] = "dud"
        cursor.updateRow(row)

    del cursor

# attempt to fix 'multi' ordinates by splitting and adding to table
split_xs = [] #independent list
split_ys = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # check for multiple x ordinates
        if row[2]=="multi" or row[3]=="multi":
            rowvals = list(row)  # need to convert to list
            # remove any zone indexes for x ordinate, i.e. 56J
            rowvals[0] = rowvals[0].replace("56J",'')
            # remove any zone indexes for y ordinate, i.e. UTM
            #row[1]
            rowvals[1] = rowvals[1].replace("UTM",'')#consider that coordinate prefix could be in wrong columns too.
#not sure about this part
            for i in range(len(rowvals)):
                xs = rowvals[0].split(' ')
                ys = rowvals[1].split(' ')
                numrows= len(xs)
#split coords here.

            #num_rows = len(xs)....

#for i in range(num_rows):....

            # think of a check for the xs and ys, i.e. same number of rows
            # append the parts to split xs and ys to later processing
            if len(xs) == len(ys):
                for index in range (len(xs)):
                    split_xs.append(xs[index])
                    split_ys.append(ys[index])
del cursor

# insert split xs and ys as new rows
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(in_table,fields) as cursor:
    for index in range(len(split_xs)):
        newrow = [split_xs[index],split_ys[index], row[4]] #, row[4] - 4 is the UID
        # check ordinates
        if len(split_xs[index]) == 6:
            newrow.append ('ok')
        else:
            newrow.append ('dud')
        if len(split_ys[index]) == 6:
            newrow.append ('ok')
        else:
            newrow.append ('dud')
        # add zero values for output ordinates
        newrow.append (0)
        newrow.append (0)
        cursor.insertRow(newrow)
    del cursor

#this is needed as the multi that are not prefixed or separated by a space are not included.
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(in_table,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # original coordinates still to long
        if row[0] > 6 or row[1] > 7:
            row[2] = "dud"

    del cursor

# attempt to convert 'ok' to output ordinates
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # convert x ordinates if 'ok'
        if row[2] =="ok":
            try:
                row[5] = float(row[1])
            except:
                row[2] =="dud"
        # convert y ordinates if 'ok'
        if row[3] =="ok":
            try:
                row[6] = float(row[1])
            except:
                row[3] =="dud"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
    del cursor

print 'Done'
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  I recommend that you edit your question to only include a code snippet that works up until where you are stuck, and the precise error that comes from that code.  Otherwise it looks like the category of question which is discussed at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/what-to-do-about-whats-wrong-with-my-wall-of-text-type-questions

Comment: Like PolyGeo said, cut the code down a bit, but it would also be nice to see a *good* and *bad* row example to see what kind of data you're dealing with. Note: with your add field it can be done like this: *arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, "CODE_X", "TEXT",field_length = 20)* fields are NULLABLE by default and you can skip the in between parameters by stating the one that you are providing a value for.